# How to get all embeds_many items in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm Using Mongoid and I have two models:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_many :tickets

  field :email, type: String

end

class Ticket
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embedded_in :user

  field :body, type: String

end
```

How can I do get all records from `Ticket` for any users?
When I use `Ticket.all`, I get `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Bad but working answer

```rb
User.all.map { |user| user.tickets }.flatten
```

It's working but it gonna make N request to you database (N=number of user), don't  know if there is another way of doing this with mongoid.